# TFLint annotation issue

Tags: terraform, tflint

I have followed TFLints document to disable TFLints error on specific line. But it's not working.

Document link which I have followed - https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/annotations.md

Source code -

```
module "ecr" {
  source = "../../../ecr"

  name = format("%s-%s", var.name, var.env)
  // tflint-ignore: terraform_unused_declarations, all, other_rule
  tags = var.tags
}
```

Error log -

```
Run tflint --color --recursive --minimum-failure-severity=error
Failed to prepare rule checking; aws/applications/aberration-detection/ecr/ecr.tf:6,10-18: Reference to undeclared input variable; An input variable with the name "tags" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "tags" {} block. working_dir=aws/applications/aberration-detection/ecr:

Error: Reference to undeclared input variable

  on aws/applications/aberration-detection/ecr/ecr.tf line 6, in module "ecr":
   6:   tags = var.tags

An input variable with the name "tags" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "tags" {} block.
```

TFLint Annotation should work and ignore the error for which annotation is defined.

Comment: That is not a lint issue, you have an actual error, the tags variable does not exist in that module, if you want to keep that line of code you can keep it as a comment`// tags = var.tags`

Comment: Also is good pointing out that a variable not been declared is not the same as an unused declaration, you can read more here:
https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-terraform/blob/v0.5.0/docs/rules/terraform_unused_declarations.md